# Why does my background image not fit my div container

Tags: html, css

When I place a background image in my div to create a background for it a scrollbar horizontally for the whole webpage. I think it is because my `background-size: cover;` made the background image grow to its original size but I want the image to scale down exactly to fit all devices.
[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Javscript/pen/WNXmRMp?editors=1100

Comment: Background size `cover` makes the image grow to fill the whole div. Background size `contain` makes the whole image fit inside the div, but then you might get borders if the div is not the same aspect ratio as the image.

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: Are you setting the width of the image to be `100vw`?  It looks like it is spilling over to the right the same amount that it is offset on the left.

Comment: No, I am not setting the image size to 100vw.

Comment: Regardless, it is the width of the image that is causing it to overflow to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar has nothing to do with the background image, not even with the element which has the background image. (Btw., a background image can never affect box sizing.)

The .main-con element has a width of 100% and a margin of 160px. The 100% does not refer to the remaining space; it refers to the width of the parent element, in this case the body.

So the .main-con element is as big as the body/screen, but has a 160px distance from the left side, resulting in it overflowing 160px on the right side.

One way to counteract this without completly reimplementing your website would be to set the width of the .main-con element to calc(100% - 160px).

Comment: I are you asking me to calculate 100%-160 because when I did I got -60;

Comment: In CSS, you can write ```width: calc(100% - 160px)```. This will result in the element being 160px less wide than its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this property:

`background-size: contain;`

`background-repeat: no-repeat;;`

The difference between the values cover and contain is that:

1- cover: makes the background covers the whole div

2- size: makes the background fits inside the div

Comment: This approach will squash the images aspect ratio which is unfavorable.

Comment: I tried this it left a blank spot in the div and the scrollbar is still there

Answer (score 0):

You gave your background Image a size of 100%. But you have allso ur Sidebar. So the Image itself cant take all 100% of the screen. Try using
calc(100% - 160px)
for the with of the .main-con

Comment: While this works, it relies on a magic number to set the width.  If the sidebar changes width for any reason it will break the layout again.